# SASS conditional imports based on env variables using webpack (to use different themes per environment)

Tags: webpack, sass, environment-variables

For my Vue website project using a single style sheet generated using Webpack from SASS I want to have:

**Conditional SASS imports based on an env variable**

---

EXAMPLE SETUP:

***`.env`*** : So for instance if I have an env containing:

```
SASS_THEME="soft"
```

***`soft.scss`*** : A SASS theme file containing something like:

```
$color-alpha: #e5e5e5;
```

***`main.scss`*** : A main sass file looking something like:

```
// Import theme variables here
@import '${SASS_THEME}';

body{
    background: $color-alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use webpack aliases. It should be a path to the file with theme.

```
const env = require('./.env');
...
const theme = getThemeFromEnv(env); // you need to implement this method
...
resolve: {
 alias: {
  @SASS_THEME: theme
 }
}
```

and then use it in scss file:

```
// Import theme variables here
@import '@SASS_THEME';

body{
    background: $color-alpha;
}
```

UPD
to load .env file use raw-loader:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.env$/,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
],
```

it will load anything as raw string

UPD2
I've got it how to load `.env` with `dotenv` package

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});

console.log(dotenv.parsed) // output { SASS_THEME: 'soft' }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, although I still do not get things to work properly. I have added your solution, with a small change to make it work (Sass needs a `~` in front of the variable name. If I now write a function that returns a string it works. But I cannot require the .env file in my webpack config, I guess require tries to parse a file as javascript, causing the webpack build to error. If you have any additional ideas I would be very grateful, for the first part did work.

Comment: @RogiervanderHeijden yeah i forgot about `~`, thanks. Updated the answer, try to use raw-loader

Comment: !nickbullock thanks again! Although I do not get it working still... I think raw-loader acts similar to dotenv which I tried earlier and it's functionality is only be available in my application itself, not in the webpack config where the raw-loader is setup.

Comment: My Man! I was ready to give up, but your solution worked perfect! Thank you for helping me out! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Rogier glad to hear that =)