# Use env variable as alias in webpack config

Tags: webpack, environment-variables

I have a use case to have a different Webpack alias on an environment variable.

In this case `process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE` returns `undefined` during the webpack build, while returning my set variable in the application itself.

Webpack config would have something like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@my_path': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${ENV.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}`),
    }
},
```

NOTE: I can find many solutions for making your .env variables available in your final application, but nothing useful to use it in your webpack config itself...

Answer (score 1):

Working answer copied from an answer by @nickbullock on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086681/sass-conditional-imports-based-on-env-variables-using-webpack-to-use-different/59089802?noredirect=1#comment104434584_59089802) :

Add this to the top of your webpack config (build in some checks if necessary):

```
const DotEnv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});

const variableFromEnv = () => {
  return DotEnv.parsed['MY_ENV_VARIABLE'];
};
```

Than call your funtion to return your variable in the config object:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@my_path': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${variableFromEnv()}`),
    }
},
```